# httpclient.execute(httppost) throws exception

Tags: android

I am using Google distance matrix api for getting distance between locations.So I used this query:

```
String distanceofloc="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="+mylat+","+mylng+"&destinations="+placeloc+"&key=MY_BROWSER_KEY";
```

Then I called a function using this String for getting distance:

```
String dis=setDistance(distanceofloc);
```

Here is My **setDistance** function:

```
public String setDistance(String url) throws URISyntaxException{
    String dis=null;
    StringBuilder placesBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        //execute search

        HttpClient placesClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse placesResponse=null;
            //try to fetch the data
        try{
            HttpPost placesGet = new HttpPost(url);


            try{
                placesResponse = placesClient.execute(placesGet);

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.v("PLACES", "exception thrown");
            }

            StatusLine placeSearchStatus = placesResponse.getStatusLine();



            if (placeSearchStatus.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                //we have an OK response


                HttpEntity placesEntity = placesResponse.getEntity();
                InputStream placesContent = placesEntity.getContent();
                //create reader
                InputStreamReader placesInput = new InputStreamReader(placesContent);
                //use buffered reader to process
                BufferedReader placesReader = new BufferedReader(placesInput);
                //read a line at a time, append to string builder
                String lineIn;
                while ((lineIn = placesReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    placesBuilder.append(lineIn);
                }}}
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.v("PLACES", "missing value");
                }




    try {
        //parse JSON

        //create JSONObject, pass stinrg returned from doInBackground

        JSONObject distanceJSONObject = new JSONObject(placesBuilder.toString());

        JSONArray rowArray = distanceJSONObject.getJSONArray("rows");

        JSONObject rowsObject = rowArray.getJSONObject(0);//only one element in this array


        JSONArray elementsArray = rowsObject.getJSONArray("elements");

        JSONObject elementsObject = elementsArray.getJSONObject(0);//only one element in this array
        if(elementsObject.isNull("distance")){

        }
        else{
       JSONObject distanceObject = elementsObject.getJSONObject("distance");
       if(!distanceObject.isNull("text"))
       { 
        dis=distanceObject.getString("text"



       }

    }



    }catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }


    return dis;

}
```

Here,Exception is thrown at

```
HttpPost placesGet = new HttpPost(url);


            try{
                placesResponse = placesClient.execute(placesGet);

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.v("PLACES", "exception thrown");
            }
```

Can anybody tell me if something is wrong with url?any help is appreciated.

Comment: please post your logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not allowed to do any network io on the main UI thread. The Android Framework provides specific ways to work around this limitation. You should either use [Worker Threads or AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads) for all the Network related things that you do.

Edit:

This was my original suggestion. It might be useful for someone else.

From the top of my mind, do you have the permission in your `Manifest.xml` to access the Internet? Something along the lines of

```
<manifest ...>
  ...
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

This is known to cause an exception when trying to connect to any server.

Comment: Can you post the exception that you get?

Comment: See my update in the answer. It probably won't hurt to read the whole site on Processes and Threads to give you an understanding of how it works.

Comment: what if I call this method from async task,will it work?

Comment: The network call should succeed in an async task, yes. However, maybe you will need to rewrite other parts, because you don't have direct access to the UI anymore.